# how to get the element with text in xpath1.0

Tags: xpath-1.0

when i use text as follow , but it doesn't work

//button[contains(text(),"Project Association")]

how to get the element "button" with specific text in xpath 1.0

```
<div data-v-e252fc6a="" class="toolbar">
    <button data-v-e252fc6a="" type="button" tabindex="1" class="aui-button aui-button--default">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <i data-v-e252fc6a="" class="aui-svg associate"></i>
        " 
            Project Association
           "
    </button>
    <button data-v-e252fc6a="" type="button" tabindex="1" class="aui-button aui-button--default">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <i data-v-e252fc6a="" class="aui-svg dissociate"></i>
                " 
            Cancel Project Management
           "
        </button>
</div>
```

//button[contains(text(),"Project Association")]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the "Normalize-Space" element instead of your "contains" element?

I would suggest you try the following:

```
//button[normalize-space() = 'Project Association']
```

This should select the  element with the text "Project Association" in your example code.

Otherwise you can try:

```
//button[text()='Project Association']
```

Comment: i have tried this, but it doesn't work too. `code` //button[normalize-space() = 'Project Association']

Comment: Have you tried //button[text()='Project Association'] instead? What error do you get?

Comment: yes , i have tried 2 ways that you suggested，but they do not work

Comment: Can you check for a test if the following gives you a result : //button[contains(., 'Project Association')]